# Google Drive Api Creating folder error

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm creating a google drive c# application and I'm having an error that I don't know how to solve.  When I try to create a folder I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertRequest' to
>   'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload'

Here is the code:

```
File body = new File();
body.Title = "NewFolder";
body.Description = "testtest";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
// service is an authorized Drive API service instance

FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body);
request.Upload();
File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

Comment: Error message isn't clear? Cannot implicitly convert type `InsertRequest` to `InsertMediaUpload`. I'm not familiar with google-drive-sdk but check they have an explicit conversation or not.

Comment: I have done it with java script but this link might help you using C# 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_a_list_of_collections

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to upload media to a folder. Folders don't have media so what you're trying to do makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this var or FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload instead:

```
File body = new File();
body.Title = "NewFolder";
body.Description = "testtest";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
// service is an authorized Drive API service instance


var request = service.Files.Insert(body);
request.Upload();
File file = request.ResponseBody;
```